# STM32F303VC : device not found

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery

I am using STM32F303VC board, and using keil-5 tool for programming.I got demo program for STM32F303VC board provided by ST microelectronics.So, when I open this demo program (I have connected my board with system) I got this error:-

[image]

I don't know what is the reason for this, so please help me get out from this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, I have to install legacy support for my device.
[this is the download link...](http://www2.keil.com/mdk5/legacy/)